# Best way to implement custom view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

[image: View to do]

I'm looking for the best and fastest way to implement view pictured above and I need advice.
I should manually build views, subviews, cells and menus from the scratch or use NSTableView and modify in some way? Maybe some third way?

Answer (score 0):

The views seem straightforward enough. Just use the standard views and subviews, image views etc. to build them. For the reordering of row functionality, you want to use a table view (with your custom cells).

This seems to me the fastest way to prototype, test and deploy.

Comment: But may I have different cells (`NSTextFieldCell`, `NSPopUpButtonCell`)  differnt Formatters in the same column of NSTableView? In IB it's impossible to set, manually maybe... I don't know.